# How to Find specific values in oracle

Tags: oracle

i Have some values  in my table like this,
column1
`50,52,53,54,56,57,58,60,61,63,75 50,53,54 54,75`

i want find values containing
`53,54` 
returns
`50,52,53,54,56,57,58,60,61,63,75 50,53,54`
rows

or `50,52,53`
returns
`50,52,53,54,56,57,58,60,61,63,75`

i tried;
`WHERE Regexp_like(DIST_GRP,('53,54]'))`

Answer (score 1):

You can search for each number in the column and use `AND` to combine the filters:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  ','||column1||',' LIKE '%,54,%'
AND    ','||column1||',' LIKE '%,75,%'
```

or

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  ','||column1||',' LIKE '%,50,%'
AND    ','||column1||',' LIKE '%,52,%'
AND    ','||column1||',' LIKE '%,53,%'
```

or you can split the string and count to make sure you have all the matches:

```sql
SELECT t.*
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT 1
         FROM   DUAL
         WHERE  REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.column1, '\d+', 1, LEVEL) IN (50, 52, 53)
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(t.column1, '\d+')
         HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.column1, '\d+', 1, LEVEL)) = 3
       )
```

or you can create a collection data type and split the string and re-aggregate into that:

```sql
CREATE TYPE int_list AS TABLE OF INT;
```

then

```sql
SELECT t.*
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT CAST(
                  COLLECT(
                    TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.column1, '\d+', 1, LEVEL))
                  )
                  AS INT_LIST
                ) AS list
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(t.column1, '\d+')
       ) l
WHERE  INT_LIST(50,52,53) SUBMULTISET OF l.list;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f90d4e7fdaef8ee6c87d08c9f13f4e88)*

Comment: i must use query like this :) 
`('50,52,53')` or `(50,75)`

Comment: @user10823899 What does "returns only nearest rows" mean? Please give a [MRE] to replicate the issue.

Comment: i'm sory
when condition is 50,52,53 query return a row but condition is 50,53 no rows return

Comment: @user10823899 They all work fine for me [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=56ac4d87613a7ca6d8d1d097edfa004c).

Comment: @user10823899 No-one can help if you don't say what the problem is.

Comment: condition is `50,53,75`

result,
`50,52,54,57,58,60,61,62,63,75
50,52,53,55,56,57,58,59,61,62,63
50,52,53,54,55,57,58,60,61,62
50,52,54,55,56,57,58,60,61,62,63,75
50,52,54,56,57,58,60,62,63,75`

i tried again but now there is another problem
example
`50,52,54,57,58,60,61,62,63,75
this line not return

Comment: @user10823899 I cannot understand what you mean by the example posted in comments; please edit a fiddle and give me a link to it that shows the running code with your issues.

Comment: sorry i didint explain it
for example ;
condition is; (50,53,76)..
with this condition
this result `50,52,54,57,58,60,61,62,63,75`  should not come because "53" is not in this row

Comment: @user10823899 None of the answers I gave return rows when less than all the required elements are found [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=04148860e59f3d5226f735f60f9f56bc).

Comment: i must  find only  contains all of condition

Comment: @user10823899 I am failing to understand what the issue you are having is as all my answers only return rows if all of the conditions are found in the list. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69659400/edit) your question with a [MRE] that includes multiple rows of sample data and your expected output and an (English, not code) explanation of why each row should or should not be included.

Comment: OK 
İm too sorry i didnt change here \d+', 1, LEVEL)) = **2**